# Why is my req.body always empty on POST?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

There are many questions that are the same, with answers, but most answers I have found revolve around the use of body-parser, which I am using. I have written many basic APIs and have never had this issue. No matter what I do, the attributes are not being saved due to the empty req.body.

**server.js**

```
'use strict'

//basic server setup
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Routes = require('./routes.js');
var config = require('./config');

// use body parser to parse requests
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));

//connect to db
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; //temp fix for mongoose promise deprecation warning
mongoose.connect(config.url);

//set port to env or 8080
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

//setup routes
var router = express.Router();

//use the imported routes
app.use('/', Routes);

//start the server and log
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server listening on %s', port);
```

**routes.js**

```
'use strict'

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Model = require('./model.js');

var count = 0;

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    count++;
    console.log('API hit count = %s', count);
    next();
});

// /model post(create new model) get(see all models)
router.route('/model')
.post(function(req,res) {
    var model = new Model();
    model.newKey = req.body.newKey;
    model.newVal = req.body.newVal;

//save the model and checkfor errors
    model.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.json({message: "Model created!"});
        }    
    });

})

.get(function(req, res) {
    console.log('made it to GET')
    Model.find(function(err, models) {
        if (err) res.send(err);

        res.json(models);
    })
});

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

var post = function() {
    var newKey = $('#postKey').val();
    var newVal = $('#postVal').val();
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/model", true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.send({
        newKey: newKey,
        newVal: newVal
    });

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log('>>>> ', JSON.parse(this.responseText));
       }
    };
}

var get = function() {
    console.log('Get Button working')
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/model");
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log('>>>> ', JSON.parse(this.responseText));
       }
    };
}
```

Comment: I believe you'd need to `.send(JSON.stringify(...your object ...))`

Comment: If you set your `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");` then you need to use `JSON.stringify(...your object ...)` as @JaromandaX said. if you set your `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` then you need to `serialize` your `object`.

Comment: Absolutely, frustratingly fantastic. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set your

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

then you need to use

```
JSON.stringify(...your object ...)
```

as @JaromandaX said. 
if you set your

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

then you need to `serialize` your `object` by `object.serialize();`.

Comment: Ataur, a follow up question. Check out my GET request. I want to pass in a value to search the DB for. For example, I want to send in parameter getKey, which will be a key name entered via Angular front end. I have tried adding url + "?value=value" etc, but no luck.

Comment: Did you received data in server end? did you print then? what is the full url then?

Comment: I am not getting data server-side. Basically, if I try following along with this example:
I get nothing. My url would be http://localhost:8080/model?newKey=getKey


    var get = function() {
        var getKey = $('#getKey').val();
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/model?newKey=" + getKey);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

Comment: Can you check `var key = req.param('newKey'); console.log(key);`

Comment: That shows the value, and I fixed the issue based off this. I have never had to do this before though. Am I missing something?